# Jquery: move the right container only

Tags: jquery, selector, mouseover

I have done the following code for a list of pics, when the user mouseover the picture an alt is showing up:

I would like to know if there is anyway I can move the mouseover'ed element only and not all of them like i do now.

```
#{list items:gallery.listPictures(), as:'picture'}
    <a class="pic" href="@{Galleries.showPicture(picture.id)}"><img src="@{Application.getPicture(picture.id)}" alt="${picture.name}" />
        <span class="alt">${picture.name}</span>
    </a>
#{/list}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".pic").mouseover(function(event){
    $(".alt").css({'top': event.pageY, 'left': event.pageX});  
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".pic").mouseover(function(event){
    $(this).find(' > span').css({'top': event.pageY, 'left': event.pageX});  
});
</script>
```

Notice the `$(this)`. Inside a jQuery function `this` will access the current element that fired the event.

See [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [jQuery child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) and [jQuery .find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: nice, is it possible to select the .alt class inside the "this", thats what I want to be able to move

Comment: maybe something like this $(this).find(' > span'). Updated answer to match